# Memory leak in Swift when binding memory

Tags: swift, memory-leaks, metal

I've come across a memory leak in Swift on the Mac. I'm creating a buffer for a calculation on the GPU using Metal. The storage created for these is automatically deleted when they are out of scope UNLESS I bind the contents to memory.

In this case, the memory is not deleted even when both the buffer and the bound pointer are out of scope.

I tried manually deallocating the buffer, but this fails since the memory was not allocated using malloc.

Is there a way to manage this memory to avoid a leak, or is this a bug in Swift on the Mac?

Any other thoughts?

Thank you very much,

Colin

```
let intensityBuff = myGPUData.device?.makeBuffer(length: MemoryLayout<Float>.stride * Int(myStars.nstars * myStars.npatch * myStars.npatch, options: .storageModeShared)

let intensityPointer = intensityBuff?.contents().bindMemory(to: Float.self,                                                       capacity: MemoryLayout<Float>.stride * Int(myStars.nstars * myStars.npatch * myStars.npatch))
```

Answer (score 0):

Metal buffers need to have the flag `MTLPurgeableState.empty` set to indicate they can be cleared out of memory after you are done using them. For example:

```
intensityBuff!.setPurgeableState(MTLPurgeableState.empty)
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the issue is that not all of Apple's code has been ported to Swift - the bindMemory command is actually written in Objective-C.

For these functions, ARC doesn't work automatically - instead you need to include the code within an autoreleasepool block e.g.

```
autorelease {
code with bindMemory statement in 
}
```

I haven't tested out the MTLPurgeableState.empty suggested above by Nate (thank you for that suggestion), since the autorelease works fine.

And of course, Apple doesn't tell you which of the functions are Objective-C based - at least not that I could find!